# Trying to call jlist method method removeelement getting error saying method is undefined

Tags: java

I am trying to remove a item from my JList.  I got the following code from a solution on Stack Overflow use the method removeElement.  When I try to do it I get a error saying the method is undefined.
code (Java version 9):

```
list.removeElement(list.getSelectedValue());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That method, `removeElement(...)` is part of the DefaultListModel, not the JList. You need to first call `getModel()` on the JList, cast it to the DefaultListModel (after first checking that it is this type) and then call the method.

e.g.,

```
ListModel model = list.getModel();
if (model instanceof DefaultListModel && list.getSelectedValue() != null) {
    ((DefaultListModel) model).removeElement(list.getSelectedValue());
}
```

Relevant API entries:

- [`JList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html)
- [`ListModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/ListModel.html)
- [`DefaultListModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html)